# remove large file from chef cache after chef-client runs

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, diskspace

I have a chef recipe that deploys about 300 megs of `.tar.gz` files.  These files are simply uploaded to chef with `knife upload cookbooks`.  After this recipe runs, and is then removed from the node's runlist.  A cache of these files persists.  I am working with an embedded system and I need to reclaim this space. however if I delete the files, running other recipe puts the files back.  Can I tell chef to not sync the files if they aren't part of the run list?  How can I skip ever syncing these files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use a cookbook file for this. Use `remote_file` instead which gives  you much more fine grained control over the file’s lifecycle.